# How to Translate a line from point a to point b when the user drag a line Android

Tags: java, android, canvas, path, sdk

Hi am trying to figure out how to translate a line from point A to point B in android canvas. I don't want to change the starting position or ending position of the line I just want to move the line across the screen.  For example

```
      matrix.setTranslate(BottomPivotX,BottomPivotY);
        Handle1.moveTo(startX,startY);
        Handle1.lineTo(BottomRightControlPointX,BottomRightControlPointY);
       // Handle1.close();
         Handle1.transform(matrix);
        canvas.drawPath(Handle1,this.CurveColor);
```

I got the line to move when the user drag there finger on screen but now the line doesn't move exactly to the user finger. it has a big off set. I am wondering how could I get the line to move exactly to the user X and Y pos on screen using this method.

Thanks

Please help

Comment: You could draw an rectangle which canvas.drawRect which looks like a line. Then override on touch and then calculate the distance moved x and y and reset the rectangle left,top,right and bottom. call invalidate to refresh the view

Comment: I kinda solve my problem using matrix but now Matrix.setTransaltion() does not m atch does not match eventX and event.y

Comment: I have posted my sample. let me know if it fits your requirement. its a custom view with a rect drawn.

Comment: is the answer not useful or have i misunderstood the question?